# How can I order, limit and filter in a single query using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

```
try:    
     keyword = Keyword.objects[:1].order_by('-created_at').get(keyword='myfilterkeyword')
except Keyword.DoesNotExist as e:
     Logger.log(e)
```

For now I do it using the above way.  Is this the optimal and right way to do it? Is exception handling the only way to detect missing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it in MongoEngine is:

```
keyword = Keyword.objects(keyword='myfilterkeyword').order_by('-created_at').first()
```

If there is no document with this keyword your variable `keyword` will be `None`.